# Exlpaination of Assembly loading difference between function and class

Tags: powershell, class, .net-assembly

I got an issue understanding the behaviour of assembly loading in two different cases : script function and assembly.

I have a form with a button that open a `[Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::InputBox` to query a string from the user.

At the start of my project, it was a simple script function in which I loaded `` and triggered the `InputBox` as such :

```
function foo {

[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.VisualBasic")

[...] some code [...]

$newProcessName = [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::InputBox($msg, $title, $script:processNameToMonitor)
}
```

Everything was smooth. Then I decided to create a class and put that in. Everything else seems ok, but that went

> Type [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction] can't be found

The assembly is loaded before the class definition and the `InputBox` is in one of the class methods.

I suppose there is a major difference between class and script assembly loading, but I can't get which.

Could someone explain it to me?

I red that assembly should be loaded outside the assembly, prior the creation of the instance, but I can't make it work (don't even know if it's right).

Comment: see the linked answers for details on why this happens as well as workarounds. this is one of many downsides of powershell classes.

Comment: Thanks @SantiagoSquarzon. I think it's ok now. 
I created the manifest, put it next to the class and initiated the class after then `using module`. 
However, I have a new error, I think that is not related at all. I initiate a form in the class constructor, but the method I call in he script to show it has an error `Cannot call a method on a null expression` and the code is just `$this.form.Show()`